# usage of php filesize when file path is not in public folder laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

hi i have a functionality which it puts a file inside the `app/storage/uploads` the thing is i need to get the file size and put it inside the database for recording purposes here is my code so far to get the file size

```
            $tinfo      = pathinfo($thepath);
            $text       = $tinfo['extension'];
            $tfln       = $tinfo['filename'];
            $tbname         = $tinfo['basename'];

            $size = filesize($thepath);
            dd($thepath);
```

in the `$tinfo` the `$thepath` contains the path to the file name when dumped here is the value `string(54) "C:\xampp\htdocs\dummy\app\storage/uploads/jobdesc.docx"`but when i execute the code above im getting a error saying
[image]

any ideas what im doing wrong? or on how to improve my code? thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I have an inkling that the fact there are both / and \ in your file path is significant.

Comment: My first guess would be the mix of forward and back slashes.You might have to normalize that. In addition, that code seems ripe for [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

Comment: hi guys thanks for reply well it turns out the / and \ are the culprit :) thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried `filesize(storage_path('uploads/jobdesc.docx'))`?

Comment: I would add that you should always use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for the slashes so you don't run into this kind of issues.